# How do I conditionally format a cell in Google Sheets based on matching values in 2 other columns?

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

So here is what I am trying to do. I have a value in C1 let's say. I would like to like to highlight that cell if:

- The value in B1 exists somewhere else in Column B(I'll call it B*n*)
- The values for A1 and A*n* in this other row also match

So if B1 is 12:00 and A1 is Foo I want to highlight C1 if a cell(B*n*) in Column B is 12:00 and the value of A*n* is Foo.

Make sense?

Comment: The match would need to be in the same row. Essentially I am formatting cells column C if an identical row exists in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Hmmm. It seems to work but maybe I am missing something

Comment: I suppose I could have written it that way but I chose A1,B1 and C1 to show those values all in the same row. If there is a matching row, let's say row 5 where A1=A5 and B1=B5, then both C1 and C5 should be highlighted. Is that a little clearer?

Comment: So @GVashist solution does work right? It looks like it but it is a huge spreadsheet and I only did a spot check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Click the Format menu and select Conditional formatting....

2.Switch to the "Custom formula" option in the drop-down menu.

3.Add in the relevant formula, rules, and cell range.

Formula:
`=AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,COUNTIF(B:B,B1)>1)`

Cell Range: `$C` - The entire C column

4.Click Save rules.