# How do I create a conditional formula in Google Sheets based on multiple criteria and multiple sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Ok. So here is what I am trying to do. I have a column that I want to populate if multiple conditions are met. Let's call it the Rate column.

Sheet A
This sheet contains the column I want to populate. It also contains columns for:
- Time 
- Network

Sheet B
This is the sheet I am getting the value(Rate) from. This sheet contains columns for:
- Time
- Network
- Rate

What I want to do is populate the Rate column on sheet A with the Rate on Sheet B when both the Time and Network match.

Make sense?

Part 2
Maybe this is a completely different question but I'll post it here first. 
After getting the rates into Sheet A I want populate a second column called Half Rate. Half Rate is simply half of the value in the Rate column with a one condition. Half Rate will only exist if there are identical rows in Sheet A. So if there are two rows that have the same Time and Network then the Half Rate column should be populated with Rate/2.

Make sense?

Comment: I'm doing something similar with formatting in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952310/how-do-i-conditionally-format-a-cell-in-google-sheets-based-on-matching-values-i?noredirect=1#comment44324425_27952310

Answer (score 0):

would this work? Assuming that time,network,rate are in columns A,B,C of the other sheet, and leaves the current cell blank if time & netowork do not match:

```
=if(Eq(SheetB!A1,SheetB!B1),SheetB!C1,"")
```